# How create a framework and refer and use it in several application in Cocoa Application for Mac

Tags: c, cocoa, frameworks

I want to create a Cooca Framework and refer it in multipal projects. Any help is appreciated.

I have tried to google and wasted my 2 days in order to find a good video or pdf tutorial on it. Please help

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html

Comment: Hello @MattyAyOh

I have created a Cocoa Framework in my application. It has a default header file in it with the very name of the framework. 
(e.g. Project name: myFW
Header File: myFW.h)


I have created 1 objective c class in the framework (helper.h helper.m) and after that when I am trying to #import my (helper.h) in the myFW.h, 
it is giving me error that file not found.


I tried:
#import <myFW/hepler.h>
#import <hepler.h>
#import "myFW/hepler.h"
#import "hepler.h"



nothing worked. Could you please suggest what should I do?

Comment: Make sure you go to your main project file, go to `Build Phases` and check `Target Dependencies`.  Make sure your new framework is in there